# Understanding the Mutex Class

Tags: c#, mutex

I am a little confused on understanding how the `Mutex` class works.

Say I have a code like that will be executed by multiple tasks:

```
bool lockAcquired = mutex.WaitOne();

try
{
    sharedVar += 1;
}
finally
{
    if (lockAcquired) mutex.ReleaseMutex();
}
```

My understanding (correct me if I am wrong) is that moment it reaches `mutex.WaitOne()`, it will wait first for another thread to execute `ReleaseMutex()` before going on to execute the succeeding statements. Therefore, it will not go on and execute the `try..finally` statement if another thread has the lock. If it acquires the lock, then that is the time when it will proceed on executing the next codes. `lockAcquired` will be `true` then. My question is, why do I need to check if `lockAcquired` is `true` inside the `finally` statement if it will only be executed when the lock is acquired. It would mean that the `if` statement inside the `finally` block would always be executed. Thanks.

Comment: `Mutex` can be quite tricky. I would highly suggest, unless your requirements are very specific use `lock` and `Monitor`. Those should satisfy 99% of your synchronization needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58195swd.aspx), the return value is:

> `true` if the current instance receives a signal. If the current instance is never signaled, `WaitOne` never returns.

This means there is no point in checking the returned value, it will never be `false`.

Comment: Thanks, I am just confused as some examples I saw checks for the return value before calling `ReleaseMutex`.

Comment: The return value for `WaitOne()` may always be true, but for any of the timeout overloads like `WaitOne(Int32)` or `WaitOne(TimeSpan)` it will be false when the timeout period expires, so you absolutely want to check it then.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to check `lockAcquired` in this code. And if you were going to check it, you should probably check it before clobbering the state that the mutex protects.

Comment: If the code after the `WaitOne()` method is executed, then that means that the lock was acquired by the thread. What would be the use of checking if the `lockAcquired` is true?